# want convert a column of data in a txt file to a row of a csv file using unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix

want convert a column of data in a txt file to a row of a csv file using unix shell script.

The test present in the txt file as follows.

ApplChk1,
 ApplChk2,
 v_baseLoanAmountTI,
 v_plannedClosingDateField,
 downPaymentTI,
 downPaymentPercentageTI,
 downPaymentCalcTI,
 downPaymentLoanAmountTI,
 v_appraisedValueTI, 
 v_purchasePriceTI, 
 v_EstimatedPriceTI, 
 v_loanPurpose,
 v_loanType, 
 v_docTypeCB,
 v_amortizationTypeCB,
 v_Purpose_of_Refinance,
 v_LoanTerm,
 v_lockPeriodCB,
 v_original_Purchase_Price,
 v_improvementCB, 
 v_improvementsCostField,
 v_describeImprovements,
 v_originalCostRefi,
 v_subordinateLienTypeCB,
 v_buyDownContributorCB,
 _RespaLoanInformation_DRadioButton7,
 _RespaLoanInformation_DRadioButton8,
 v_subordinateFinancingCreditLineAmount,
 v_buyDownOptionCB, 
 v_cashOutPurposeCB,
 v_subordinateFinancingTI, 
 v_homeEqPurposeCB,
 v_initialDrawHomeEq,
 v_originalCostHomeEq,
 v_lienPositionCB,
 v_FirstMortgageAmountTI,
 RehabLoan

I want this content in single row of a csv file.

I have used the following code

{ for i in `< file.txt` ; do echo -n $i ; done; echo; } > out.csv

The above command displaying the above text in single column when i open out.csv in windows environment using microsoft office.

Please help me in converting above data column into row of a csv file

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is the data currently in multi-row and multi-column?

Comment: Data is in single column and multiple rows i want output as a single row

Comment: is excel not using semicolon in what it thinks is CSV? Try changing the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use Linux/BSD, you can use "tr"

Example:

```
sharuzzaman.raslan@NL-4168 ~/test1
$ cat data
Sunday
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday

sharuzzaman.raslan@NL-4168 ~/test1
$ cat data | tr '\n' ','
Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,
```

Comment: It is not working the above command is giving output like it is keeping first line as it is and keeping all other rows in a separate column

Comment: You mentioned that data is in single column. Is there anymore data other than the text you put above?

Please put at least 5 lines of data so that we can see the exact pattern

Comment: The input text is as ApplChk1,
 ApplChk2,
 v_baseLoanAmountTI,
 v_plannedClosingDateField,
 downPaymentTI,
 downPaymentPercentageTI,
 downPaymentCalcTI,
 downPaymentLoanAmountTI,
 v_appraisedValueTI, 
 v_purchasePriceTI, 
 v_EstimatedPriceTI, 
 v_loanPurpose,
 v_loanType, 
 v_docTypeCB,
and output needed as ApplChk1,
 ApplChk2,
 v_baseLoanAmountTI,
 v_plannedClosingDateField,
 downPaymentTI,
 downPaymentPercentageTI,
 downPaymentCalcTI,
 downPaymentLoanAmountTI,
 v_appraisedValueTI, 
 v_purchasePriceTI, 
 v_EstimatedPriceTI, 
 v_loanPurpose,
 v_loanType, 
 v_docTypeCB,